# Resolving ImportError: No module named arcgisscripting?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, eclipse, importerror

I am trying to run an ArcGIS python script from Eclipse and get the following message:

> ImportError: No module named arcgisscripting

I can run this in IDLE... any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I received this error last week after I modified my PYTHONPATH environment variable and misspelled my path to arcgisscripting.pyd.

Correcting the PYTHONPATH to include 'c:\Program files\ArcGIS\Bin' (spelled correctly) fixed the problem.

Comment: To clarify, I was running from a batch file...not from eclipse.

Is eclipse using a different python?  what version is your ArcGIS and the IDLE you were using?

Comment: You might want to check your eclipse config (e.g. http://www.vogella.de/articles/Python/images/pydev06.gif) and see if you're using the right version for whichever ArcGIS you are using (http://wiki.gis.com/wiki/index.php/Python).

Comment: Well, i had to update the exclipse config with the arcgis\bin path... and it's now running, really, really, slow... but it works.

Wonder why it's so slow, idle is much quicker to compile.

Comment: perhaps eclipse is scanning the arcgis\bin (perhaps recursively)?  maybe try moving the arcgisscripting.pyd to an empty directory and updating your eclipse config? (**i don't know eclipse so take my suggestions w/ a grain of salt**)

Comment: or maybe first, run procmon.exe (SysInternals http://goo.gl/J5nW)  and see if there's anything obvious that jumps out.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that when you configure eclipse, you configure that you set up the arcgis bindings, located under esri's (or arcgis) folder in program files.