# Run FME Script in batch file using .NET

Tags: arcpy, fme-form, python-2.7

Encountered another roadblock. I have a working FME script that I want to automatically run using a console app.

I created a simple batch file which accepts a MDB file path as parameter:

```
  fme.exe E:\sample.fmw --SourceDataset_GEODATABASE_MDB "%1"
```

when I run this batch file, everything works well.

But when I try to do the same thing only in my console application using the following  code:

```
processInfo = New ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c C:\executeFME.bat C:\sampleFile.mdb")
processInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
processInfo.UseShellExecute = False
processInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True

process__1 = Process.Start(processInfo)
process__1.WaitForExit()

Dim output As String = process__1.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
Dim [error] As String = process__1.StandardError.ReadToEnd()

Dim exitCode = process__1.ExitCode                   
Console.WriteLine("ExitCode: " & exitCode.ToString(), "ExecuteCommand"
process__1.Close()
```

I get the error "**Python Exception : No module named arcgisscripting**"

I have a Startup python script that will check the geometries of the supplied mdb file and this is where it errors out.

Do I still need to configure something to make it to work?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

I noticed in the log files that the manually executed batch file using the correct Python Interpreter: **C:\Windows\SysWOW64\python27.dll** while the batch file executed by the console app uses a different one: **C:\apps\FME\fmepython27\python27.dll**. I tried modifying the Interpreter settings by using:

```
fme.exe APPLY_SETTINGS SYSTEM "Python/Python Interpreter" c:/windows/SysWOW64/python27.dll
```

Ran it again and it was still using the old interpreter. I think this is the cause of this but I'm out of ideas on how to fix it. Please help!

Comment: Could this answer help you? http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/389/7424
Or this one? http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/27116/7424

Comment: Thanks for the reply Fezter. I actually did that already. As it turns out. My previous comment actually fixed the error, i just had to restart the server. Everything seems to be working now.

Answer (score 1):

These settings configuration fixed the issue:

```
fme.exe APPLY_SETTINGS SYSTEM "Python/Use Custom Python" true
fme.exe APPLY_SETTINGS SYSTEM "Python/Python Interpreter" c:/windows/SysWOW64/python27.dll
```

I just had to restart the server after i applied the changes. This will just force FME to use ArcGIS' Phyton Interpreter which carries the arcgisscripting.

Answer (score 1):

The other way to get FME to use a different interpreter is under Tools > Options > Runtime in the Workbench menu:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mark, I actually did that too but it only seems to save the settings on the specific user that changed it(I might have missed a step). That's why I was encountering the issue because i was executing the batch file remotely.